# How to pass a variable containing coordinates in to geojson 'coordinates' field?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am trying to plot a polygon on mapboxgl by passing a variable that contains an array of coordinates after some mathematical calculations, into the field 'coordinates' of the map.addLayer function. Not sure if this is the correct way.

Did not manage to display the polygon with no error message.

```
map.addLayer({
        'id' : "layer1",
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': {
            'type': 'geojson',
                'data': {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'Polygon',
                    'coordinates': [variable]
                }
            }
        },
                'layout': {},
                'paint': {
                'fill-color': '#cb4b16',
                'fill-opacity': 0.8
                }
     });
```

Here are the coordinates generated:

```
[103.7721606585124334, 1.3885039360043285],[103.7721665513856095, 1.3885034225235453],[103.7721723986707616, 1.3885023864315598],[103.7721781772912948, 1.3885008318173533],[103.7721838644416437, 1.3884987648162785],[103.7721894376772411, 1.3884961935858440],[103.7721948750030521, 1.3884931282735218],[103.7722001549604443, 1.3884895809766988],[103.7722052567118425, 1.3884855656949355],[103.7722101601229525, 1.3884810982747144],[103.7722148458422566, 1.3884761963469021],[103.7722192953773686, 1.3884708792571681],[103.7722234911679919, 1.3884651679896367],[103.7722274166552694, 1.3884590850840712],[103.7722310563470955, 1.3884526545469213],[103.7722343958792663, 1.3884459017565793],[103.7722374220721804, 1.3884388533632233],[103.7722401229828222, 1.3884315371836418],[103.7722424879519423, 1.3884239820914532],[103.7722445076460787, 1.3884162179031552],[103.7722461740944340, 1.3884082752604512],[103.7722474807202815, 1.3884001855093238],[103.7722484223669852, 1.3883919805763247],[103.7722489953182929, 1.3883836928425759],[103.7722491973130161, 1.3883753550159763],[103.7722490275539826, 1.3883670000021182],[103.7722484867111490, 1.3883586607744245],[103.7722475769189714, 1.3883503702440168],[103.7722463017679928, 1.3883421611298310],[103.7722446662906464, 1.3883340658294905],[103.7722426769414170, 1.3883261162914475],[103.7722403415713615, 1.3883183438888969],[103.7722376693971000, 1.3883107792959604],[103.7722346709645080, 1.3883034523666304],[103.7722313581070068, 1.3882963920169498],[103.7722277438989522, 1.3882896261108932],[103.7722238426039496, 1.3882831813504006],[103.7722196696186501, 1.3882770831699975],[103.7722152414119137, 1.3882713556364161],[103.7722105754598374, 1.3882660213536144],[103.7722056901768184, 1.3882611013735697],[103.7722006048428227, 1.3882566151131959],[103.7721953395273573, 1.3882525802777126],[103.7721899150101876, 1.3882490127907725],[103.7721843526994405, 1.3882459267316163],[103.7721786745469927, 1.3882433342795102],[103.7721729029619269, 1.3882412456656776],[103.7721670607220545, 1.3882396691329237],[103.7721611708840044, 1.3882386109031029],[103.7721552566923151, 1.3882380751525645],[103.7721493414875624, 1.3882380639956715],[103.7721434486143863, 1.3882385774764547],[103.7721376013292343, 1.3882396135684403],[103.7721318227087011, 1.3882411681826468],[103.7721261355583522, 1.3882432351837215],[103.7721205623227547, 1.3882458064141561],[103.7721151249969438, 1.3882488717264783],[103.7721098450395516, 1.3882524190233012],[103.7721047432881534, 1.3882564343050645],[103.7720998398770433, 1.3882609017252856],[103.7720951541577392, 1.3882658036530979],[103.7720907046226273, 1.3882711207428320],[103.7720865088320039, 1.3882768320103633],[103.7720825833447265, 1.3882829149159288],[103.7720789436529003, 1.3882893454530787],[103.7720756041207295, 1.3882960982434207],[103.7720725779278155, 1.3883031466367768],[103.7720698770171737, 1.3883104628163583],[103.7720675120480536, 1.3883180179085468],[103.7720654923539172, 1.3883257820968449],[103.7720638259055619, 1.3883337247395489],[103.7720625192797144, 1.3883418144906763],[103.7720615776330106, 1.3883500194236753],[103.7720610046817029, 1.3883583071574241],[103.7720608026869797, 1.3883666449840237],[103.7720609724460132, 1.3883749999978818],[103.7720615132888469, 1.3883833392255756],[103.7720624230810245, 1.3883916297559833],[103.7720636982320030, 1.3883998388701690],[103.7720653337093495, 1.3884079341705096],[103.7720673230585788, 1.3884158837085525],[103.7720696584286344, 1.3884236561111032],[103.7720723306028958, 1.3884312207040397],[103.7720753290354878, 1.3884385476333696],[103.7720786418929890, 1.3884456079830503],[103.7720822561010436, 1.3884523738891068],[103.7720861573960462, 1.3884588186495994],[103.7720903303813458, 1.3884649168300025],[103.7720947585880822, 1.3884706443635839],[103.7720994245401585, 1.3884759786463856],[103.7721043098231775, 1.3884808986264303],[103.7721093951571731, 1.3884853848868042],[103.7721146604726385, 1.3884894197222875],[103.7721200849898082, 1.3884929872092275],[103.7721256473005553, 1.3884960732683838],[103.7721313254530031, 1.3884986657204899],[103.7721370970380690, 1.3885007543343224],[103.7721429392779413, 1.3885023308670763],[103.7721488291159915, 1.3885033890968972],[103.7721547433076807, 1.3885039248474356],[103.7721606585124334, 1.3885039360043285]
```

Comment: If there is no error message I assume the polygon is rendered very small OR is on a position you wouldn't expect. Can you post the coordinates in `variable`?

Comment: I have added in the coordinates in ''variable''. I'm trying to plot an ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your polygon data is working just fine.

You can use the example below to figure out if your points are properly structured.

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZmFyYWRheTIiLCJhIjoiTUVHbDl5OCJ9.buFaqIdaIM3iXr1BOYKpsQ';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
  center: [103.7721606585124334, 1.3883539360043285],
  zoom: 18
});

map.on('load', () => {

  map.addLayer({
    'id' : "layer1",
    'type': 'fill',
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
      'fill-color': '#cb4b16',
      'fill-opacity': 0.8
    },
    'source': {
      'type': 'geojson',
        'data': {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
          'type': 'Polygon',
          'coordinates': [[
             [103.7721606585124334, 1.3885039360043285],
             [103.7721665513856095, 1.3885034225235453],
             [103.7721723986707616, 1.3885023864315598],
             [103.7721781772912948, 1.3885008318173533],
             [103.7721838644416437, 1.3884987648162785],
             [103.7721894376772411, 1.3884961935858440],
             [103.7721948750030521, 1.3884931282735218],
             [103.7722001549604443, 1.3884895809766988],
             [103.7722052567118425, 1.3884855656949355],
             [103.7722101601229525, 1.3884810982747144],
             [103.7722148458422566, 1.3884761963469021],
             [103.7722192953773686, 1.3884708792571681],
             [103.7722234911679919, 1.3884651679896367],
             [103.7722274166552694, 1.3884590850840712],
             [103.7722310563470955, 1.3884526545469213],
             [103.7722343958792663, 1.3884459017565793],
             [103.7722374220721804, 1.3884388533632233],
             [103.7722401229828222, 1.3884315371836418],
             [103.7722424879519423, 1.3884239820914532],
             [103.7722445076460787, 1.3884162179031552],
             [103.7722461740944340, 1.3884082752604512],
             [103.7722474807202815, 1.3884001855093238],
             [103.7722484223669852, 1.3883919805763247],
             [103.7722489953182929, 1.3883836928425759],
             [103.7722491973130161, 1.3883753550159763],
             [103.7722490275539826, 1.3883670000021182],
             [103.7722484867111490, 1.3883586607744245],
             [103.7722475769189714, 1.3883503702440168],
             [103.7722463017679928, 1.3883421611298310],
             [103.7722446662906464, 1.3883340658294905],
             [103.7722426769414170, 1.3883261162914475],
             [103.7722403415713615, 1.3883183438888969],
             [103.7722376693971000, 1.3883107792959604],
             [103.7722346709645080, 1.3883034523666304],
             [103.7722313581070068, 1.3882963920169498],
             [103.7722277438989522, 1.3882896261108932],
             [103.7722238426039496, 1.3882831813504006],
             [103.7722196696186501, 1.3882770831699975],
             [103.7722152414119137, 1.3882713556364161],
             [103.7722105754598374, 1.3882660213536144],
             [103.7722056901768184, 1.3882611013735697],
             [103.7722006048428227, 1.3882566151131959],
             [103.7721953395273573, 1.3882525802777126],
             [103.7721899150101876, 1.3882490127907725],
             [103.7721843526994405, 1.3882459267316163],
             [103.7721786745469927, 1.3882433342795102],
             [103.7721729029619269, 1.3882412456656776],
             [103.7721670607220545, 1.3882396691329237],
             [103.7721611708840044, 1.3882386109031029],
             [103.7721552566923151, 1.3882380751525645],
             [103.7721493414875624, 1.3882380639956715],
             [103.7721434486143863, 1.3882385774764547],
             [103.7721376013292343, 1.3882396135684403],
             [103.7721318227087011, 1.3882411681826468],
             [103.7721261355583522, 1.3882432351837215],
             [103.7721205623227547, 1.3882458064141561],
             [103.7721151249969438, 1.3882488717264783],
             [103.7721098450395516, 1.3882524190233012],
             [103.7721047432881534, 1.3882564343050645],
             [103.7720998398770433, 1.3882609017252856],
             [103.7720951541577392, 1.3882658036530979],
             [103.7720907046226273, 1.3882711207428320],
             [103.7720865088320039, 1.3882768320103633],
             [103.7720825833447265, 1.3882829149159288],
             [103.7720789436529003, 1.3882893454530787],
             [103.7720756041207295, 1.3882960982434207],
             [103.7720725779278155, 1.3883031466367768],
             [103.7720698770171737, 1.3883104628163583],
             [103.7720675120480536, 1.3883180179085468],
             [103.7720654923539172, 1.3883257820968449],
             [103.7720638259055619, 1.3883337247395489],
             [103.7720625192797144, 1.3883418144906763],
             [103.7720615776330106, 1.3883500194236753],
             [103.7720610046817029, 1.3883583071574241],
             [103.7720608026869797, 1.3883666449840237],
             [103.7720609724460132, 1.3883749999978818],
             [103.7720615132888469, 1.3883833392255756],
             [103.7720624230810245, 1.3883916297559833],
             [103.7720636982320030, 1.3883998388701690],
             [103.7720653337093495, 1.3884079341705096],
             [103.7720673230585788, 1.3884158837085525],
             [103.7720696584286344, 1.3884236561111032],
             [103.7720723306028958, 1.3884312207040397],
             [103.7720753290354878, 1.3884385476333696],
             [103.7720786418929890, 1.3884456079830503],
             [103.7720822561010436, 1.3884523738891068],
             [103.7720861573960462, 1.3884588186495994],
             [103.7720903303813458, 1.3884649168300025],
             [103.7720947585880822, 1.3884706443635839],
             [103.7720994245401585, 1.3884759786463856],
             [103.7721043098231775, 1.3884808986264303],
             [103.7721093951571731, 1.3884853848868042],
             [103.7721146604726385, 1.3884894197222875],
             [103.7721200849898082, 1.3884929872092275],
             [103.7721256473005553, 1.3884960732683838],
             [103.7721313254530031, 1.3884986657204899],
             [103.7721370970380690, 1.3885007543343224],
             [103.7721429392779413, 1.3885023308670763],
             [103.7721488291159915, 1.3885033890968972],
             [103.7721547433076807, 1.3885039248474356],
             [103.7721606585124334, 1.3885039360043285]
          ]]
        }
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf@5.1.6/turf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.38.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.38.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [in the docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/) you are doing it the correct way assuming `variable` is an array of the coordinates you posted.

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxaktouy/1/) with I think is the desired result.
It is using mapbox v1.3.1. For some reason the snippet errored here on StackOverflow.

*Thanks to @rafaelcastrocouto for the access token ^^*

Comment: I'm guessing he was just missing a container array

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto I think not, the posted array is not valid JavaScript so I assumed it were the contents of an array. I'm not sure what the problem is causing for OP.